# Find Laurent Series Of $\frac{z-7}{z^2+z-2}$ at $1<|z|<2$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

$$\frac{z-7}{z^2+z-2}$$ at $1<|z|<2$

$$\frac{z-7}{z^2+z-2}=-\frac{2}{z-1}+\frac{3}{z+2}$$

in  $1<|z|<2$ both functions are analytic so it is just taylor series?

Comment: Yes it just Taylors series. The Laurent series come into play whenever we have a pole or an essential singularity.

Comment: @GuyFabrice No. Please check the keyword `Laurent series`.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not just the Taylor series.

In the case of $\frac3{z+2}$, it is, indeed. In that case, whe have\begin{align}\frac3{z+2}&=\frac3{2-(-z)}\\&=\frac32\times\frac1{1-\frac{-z}2}\\&=\frac32\left(1-\frac z2+\frac{z^2}{2^2}-\frac{z^3}{2^3}+\cdots\right)\\&=\frac32-\frac3{2^2}z+\frac3{2^3}z^2-\frac3{2^4}z^3+\cdots,\end{align}since $\left|-\frac{-z}2\right|<1$. On the other hand,\begin{align}-\frac2{z-1}&=-\frac2z\times\frac1{1-\frac1z}\\&=-\frac2z\left(1+\frac1z+\frac1{z^2}+\frac1{z^3}+\cdots\right)\\&=-\frac2z-\frac2{z^2}-\frac2{z^3}-\frac2{z^4}\cdots,\end{align}since $|z|>1$.

Comment: This is an expansion around $z=0$ which seems to not be in the given  domain

Comment: @GuyFabrice Not around the given domain?? Why? Isn't $0$ the center of $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,1<|z|<2\}$? If not, then *which point* is the center?

Comment: yes that is my point the  given function is obviously does not have any singularity. may i will check what the Laurent expansion infer. but I do remember that the point around which the expansion is done should be a singularity or any order point taken in the given domain. Maybe i am misleading ...

Comment: @GuyFabrice You are just plain wrong. Do yourself a favour and read [something](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) about Laurent series. And note that you did *not* answer my question: what is the center of the annulus $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,1<|z|<2\}$, if it is not $0$?

Comment: the center is of course $0$ but it does not belong to annulus given.

Comment: @GuyFabrice Digging deeper and deeper?

Comment: @GuyFabrice Yes, $0$ does not belong to the annulus. And... ? What do you deduce from that? That's quite common, to say the least, in the context of Laurent series.

Comment: I understand your  point now you are right :)